# How to put condition in showing items in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Location class variable in the Firebase DB and I want to use `distanceTo()` function like this:

```
adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Shops, MenuViewHolder>(Shops.class,
                R.layout.menu_item,
                MenuViewHolder.class,
                shops.orderByChild("address").distanceTo(locationofusertocompare) )
```

How to do this thing and restrict items to be shown in `RecyclerView`?

Comment: What kind of condition would you like to use?

Comment: I have mentioned I want to use distanceTo

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way in which you can filter database records, in the way you do. There is no `distanceTo()` method in Firebase. To solve such a problem, you should use a third party library named [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java):

> GeoFire is an open-source library for Android/Java that allows you to store and query a set of keys based on their geographic location. Its main benefit however, is the possibility of querying keys within a given geographic area - all in realtime.